# X86 intel syntax - ambigious size for mov, junk h after expression?

Tags: x86, gnu-assembler, att, intel-syntax

I was working with AT&T syntax but thought i'd try out intel. I have this code:

```
.text
        .global _start

_start: 
        mov ebx, 0
        mov eax, 1          
        int 80h
```

Which should return 0, right? It did with AT&T before i converted it.

I'm assembling using:

```
 as out.s -msyntax=intel --32 -o out.o
```

But I get:

```
out.s:5: Error: ambiguous operand size for `mov'
out.s:6: Error: ambiguous operand size for `mov'
out.s:7: Error: junk `h' after expression
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I thought the global directive in as is wo a

Comment: At the top of your file assembly file  `.intel_syntax noprefix`

Comment: .section .text .globl _start

Comment: @Rafael GNU assembler supports `.globl` and `.global`

Comment: And you'll need to change `int 80h` to `int 0x80` as GNU assembler doesn't support the suffixes like `h`. It uses prefixed notation to determine the base of a number `0x` for hex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Non ancient versions of GNU's Assembler provide support for Intel syntax, but there are some issues. `-msyntax=intel` isn't enough if you are looking for something closer to NASM/MASM's intel syntax. `-msyntax=intel` will switch the order of the operands so the destination is the first operand and the source operand are after. However you still need to prefix all the register names with `%` percent. So you'd likely find this would have worked:

```
    mov %ebx, 0
    mov %eax, 1
```

That would likely fix the errors on the *MOV* instructions. This is probably not what you want. To use Intel syntax without the `%` prefixes you can add this to the top of each of your assembly files:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
```

By specifying this at the top of each of your assembly files you no longer need to assemble with the option `-msyntax=intel`.

The `junk 'h' after expression` error is because GNU's assembler (even in Intel syntax mode) doesn't support constants with the base specified as a suffix. In your case `80h` isn't recognized. GNU assembler requires base to specified by a prefix like `0x` for hexadecimal. So to eliminate this error use:

```
    int 0x80
```

Fixing these issues should allow this code to assemble.